# How to submit Test Facebook App for review

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a test app on Facebook and I need to access public pages using the graph API. I have all the required permissions and valid token.

This is the API I am trying to access:
`https://graph.facebook.com/178585515507054/posts?access_token=TOKEN`

The page is a public page.

I am getting the below response.

`{
 "error": {
   "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this 
      endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page 
      Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on 
      reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "BEOCTxA6eXn"
  }
}`

Now I know that I need to submit the app for review. But my app is not ready yet. Its still in development mode. Moreover, for the test version of my app, it doesn't even show the "App review" link.

Why does FB put such restrictions on test app? How to get my test app reviewed?

Comment: Are you talking about an actual “test app”, as in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps ...? You don’t submit _that_ for review, you only use that to test and develop. You need to submit your _real_ app for review after you are done with that.

Comment: I understand that. But I am trying to access a public page (Cocacola) using the test-app. I am getting the error saying I need to get it reviewed. Is there any way to access test pages using test app?

Comment: @CBroe actually Test Apps are useless for developers since we cant use most of the APIs until we get permissions. And we can't get permissions because test app can't be submitted for review.